# how to use struts2-bean-validation-plugin to show error message and stop executing if there is error

Tags: struts2, bean-validation

I am using struts 2.5 and struts2-bean-validation-plugin 2.5, hibernate-validator 5.2.4.Final.

My java bean looks like:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class User {
    @Size(max=4)
    private String name;


}
```

struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.beanValidation.providerClass" value="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator" />
<constant name="struts.beanValidation.ignoreXMLConfiguration" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.beanValidation.convertMessageToUtf" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.beanValidation.convertMessageFromEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />

<package name="my-bean-validation" extends="struts-bean-validation">
    <action name="beanValidation" method="testBeanValidation" class="example.my.struts2.BeanValidation">
        <result name="success">/result.jsp</result>         
    </action>
</package>
```

Action class:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import example.my.model.User;

public class BeanValidation {
    @Valid
    private User user;

    public String testBeanValidation() {

        //.....
        return "success";
    }
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<s:head/>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <s:form action="beanValidation.action" method="post">
        <s:textfield name="user.name" key="name" />
        <s:textfield name="user.age" key="age" />       
        <s:submit key="submit" />
    </s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I input invalid user name, the error message only displayed in console, not on the JSP page.  Meanwhile, even there is validation error, the action `testBeanValidation` still be executed, this is not what I want.

How to show validation error message on front-end such that user can see it and how to stop executing the action method if validation failed?

Comment: You are using plain HTML tags, that is why you don't see any validation error on JSP. Use S2 tags.

Comment: @AleksandrM, I did as you said, please see my updated index.jsp, but the result are the same, what I missed?